# GA: enhanced ecommerce checkout products

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I m starting working on Enhanced Ecommerce Especially on the checkout process.
I am using [this website](https://enhancedecommerce.appspot.com/) as reference.

My question is in the checkout process, why we are obliged to send in every step the entire cart (all the products)?

Answer (score 1):

The technical reason is that, if every step of your checkout is a different page, there is no persistence between pages, so it's your responsibility to push the products on each step. Google Analytics *could have* technically done this persistence on the server side, but that would mean more work (and memory) for GA servers. Also, sometimes you want to add extra info (in the form of custom dimensions or metrics) but only for specific checkout steps, so this wouldn't really be possible if GA just "remembered" the products for you.